# systemd-resolved responds with NOERROR despite DNS server responding with NXDOMAIN

Tags: domain-name-system, systemd

I'm using Fedora 33 and systemd 246. To provide a little background, I'm having trouble with multicast DNS resolution through `nss-mdns` and have determined the [unicast SOA heuristic](https://github.com/lathiat/nss-mdns/issues/75) to be the problem.

Then I've noticed that systemd-resolved responds with a NOERROR response code even though the query it sends towards the current DNS server results in NXDOMAIN.

```
$ resolvectl status
Global
       LLMNR setting: resolve             
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
Fallback DNS Servers: 1.1.1.1             
                      8.8.8.8             
                      1.0.0.1             
                      8.8.4.4             
                      2606:4700:4700::1111
                      2001:4860:4860::8888
                      2606:4700:4700::1001
                      2001:4860:4860::8844

Link 3 (wlo1)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
DefaultRoute setting: yes                      
       LLMNR setting: yes                      
MulticastDNS setting: no                       
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                       
      DNSSEC setting: no                       
    DNSSEC supported: no                       
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.1.1              
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1              
          DNS Domain: ~.                       
                      lan
```

Query to the DNS server:

```
$ dig @192.168.1.1 -t SOA example.local

; <<>> DiG 9.11.24-RedHat-9.11.24-2.fc33 <<>> @192.168.1.1 -t SOA example.local
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 4136
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.local.                 IN      SOA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.local.          10800   IN      SOA     example.local. nobody.invalid. 1 3600 1200 604800 10800

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
explanation.invalid.    10800   IN      TXT     "Blocking is mandated by standards, see references on https://www.iana.org/assignments/special-use-domain-names/special-use-domain-names.xhtml"

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: St pro 02 16:42:24 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 254
```

Query to the systemd-resolved local DNS stub listener:

```
$ dig @127.0.0.53 -t SOA example.local

; <<>> DiG 9.11.24-RedHat-9.11.24-2.fc33 <<>> @127.0.0.53 -t SOA example.local
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5771
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.local.                 IN      SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.local.          10800   IN      SOA     example.local. nobody.invalid. 1 3600 1200 604800 10800

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: St pro 02 16:44:21 CET 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

Query using resolvectl:

```
$ resolvectl query -t SOA example.local
example.local IN SOA example.local nobody.invalid 1 3600 1200 604800 10800 -- link: wlo1

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 5.0ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

Corresponding packets captured by tcpdump:

```
$ tcpdump -n -i wlo1 port domain
listening on wlo1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
16:49:57.660945 IP 192.168.1.187.37304 > 192.168.1.1.domain: 32798+ SOA? example.local. (31)
16:49:57.664257 IP 192.168.1.1.domain > 192.168.1.187.37304: 32798 NXDomain* 0/1/1 (254)
```

Corresponding systemd-resolved log:

```
systemd-resolved[186024]: Got message type=method_call sender=:1.3283 destination=org.freedesktop.resolve1 path=/org/freedesktop/resolve1 interface=org.freedesktop.resolve1.Manager member=ResolveRecord cookie=2 reply_cookie=0 signature=isqqt error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
systemd-resolved[186024]: Looking up RR for example.local IN SOA.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=AddMatch cookie=89 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
systemd-resolved[186024]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=GetNameOwner cookie=90 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
systemd-resolved[186024]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.3260 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=90 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
systemd-resolved[186024]: Cache miss for example.local IN SOA
systemd-resolved[186024]: Transaction 13951 for <example.local IN SOA> scope dns on wlo1/*.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Using feature level UDP+EDNS0 for transaction 13951.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Using DNS server 192.168.1.1 for transaction 13951.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Sending query packet with id 13951.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Got message type=method_return sender=org.freedesktop.DBus destination=:1.3260 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=4294967295 reply_cookie=89 signature= error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
systemd-resolved[186024]: Match type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.DBus',path='/org/freedesktop/DBus',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus',member='NameOwnerChanged',arg0=':1.3283' successfully installed.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Processing incoming packet on transaction 13951 (rcode=NXDOMAIN).
systemd-resolved[186024]: Server doesn't support EDNS(0) properly, downgrading feature level...
systemd-resolved[186024]: Using degraded feature set UDP instead of UDP+EDNS0 for DNS server 192.168.1.1.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Server feature level is now lower than when we began our transaction. Restarting with new ID.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Transaction 13951 is now 31028.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Cache miss for example.local IN SOA
systemd-resolved[186024]: Transaction 31028 for <example.local IN SOA> scope dns on wlo1/*.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Using feature level UDP for transaction 31028.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Sending query packet with id 31028.
systemd-resolved[186024]: Processing incoming packet on transaction 31028 (rcode=NXDOMAIN).
systemd-resolved[186024]: Transaction 31028 for <example.local IN SOA> on scope dns on wlo1/* now complete with <success> from network (unsigned).
systemd-resolved[186024]: Sent message type=method_return sender=n/a destination=:1.3283 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=91 reply_cookie=2 signature=a(iqqay)t error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
systemd-resolved[186024]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.DBus path=/org/freedesktop/DBus interface=org.freedesktop.DBus member=RemoveMatch cookie=92 reply_cookie=0 signature=s error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
systemd-resolved[186024]: Freeing transaction 31028.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: did you want `MulticastDNS setting: no` to be `yes`?  because NXDomain is the correct response, not an error...?  also dig natively does not check mdns, look at https://www.gabriel.urdhr.fr/2019/04/02/llmnr-mdns-cli-lookup/

Comment: @JacobEvans No, Fedora 33 doesn't use systemd-resolved to resolve multicast DNS, it uses nss-mdns. And in my question I'm using dig for unicast DNS (just like it says, testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS).

Comment: And what information do you have in logfiles? `systemd-resolved` should have explained what is happening there.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've updated the question with the log, but it doesn't help much.